# Access arbitrary S3 object using amplify-angular

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have amplify-angular configured and working for authentication and API access. Using Angular 5.

Can I access private S3 resources and leverage the same authentication used during API access?

Specifically, I'd like to make a REST GET request to an S3 object such as :
`https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket-name/my-private-file.dat`

The AWS signature needs to be included as an authorization header for this to work. (assuming the user has permission)

Possible options:

- [The RestClient class](https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/api/classes/restclient.html) : It seems to do what I want, but I don't think it is exported or available to use by my application code
- API : Can I define another API in my amplify configuration as `https://s3.amazonaws.com` ? I'm not sure what side-effects are involved in treating that like an API gateway instance instead of... whatever it is.

I cannot put an API endpoint in front of S3 access; the ACLs would be easier to check based on direct S3 access, since they have individual ACLs per object.

The "Storage" module doesn't seem appropriate. That seems to only work for a pre-determined bucket. My access patterns could go to any number of buckets that are not known until runtime.

Comment: Can't you configure the Amplify Storage module to take a bucket name at runtime?  E.g. `Storage.configure`

Comment: Yes, but as I understand it, you can only configure a single bucket. My scenario may access any number of buckets, determined by the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to use the Storage module, but it's a hack.

```
const storage = this.amplifyService.storage();

const storageOptions = { 
  bucket: 'any-bucket',
  // see https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/blob/master/packages/aws-amplify/src/Storage/Storage.ts#L325
  // public appears to be the only option that doesn't append hardcoded values
  customPrefix: { 
    public: ''
  },
  level: 'public' 
};

storage.get( 'objectIdWithinBucket', storageOptions ).then( 
  data => {
    console.log( "A signed URL is returned that can be used to access the object");
    console.log( data );
  },
  error => {
    console.log( "Boo. Err. ", error );
  }
)
```

Why this works: The custom prefix and public level override the default s3 parameters. The resource isn't actually public, but any other option appends slashes and extra characters that don't belong.

The Storage module is (in my opinion) an example of bad API design: They provide values that are based on an expected use case which is undocumented. The ability to override them is not documented anywhere that I can find. Example: if you don't specify a "level", it appends "public" as a prefix to the object id.

More to the point, the Storage module assumes that signed in users are storing objects in a single bucket with a known naming convention. Changing these is difficult.

Warning: The override might assign the passed parameters into the default _options. This would occur at https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/blob/240e50b61f50eaf3712bfbc088d1b096360b401c/packages/aws-amplify/src/Storage/Storage.ts#L86 (snapshot at most recent commit at time of writing)

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work for me. When I override the bucket, the bucket name simply doesn't show up in API endpoint URL and the request fails.

Answer (score 0):

There also would be the possibility to use `<amplify-s3-image>` component.

```
<amplify-s3-image [path]="mainImage?.key" [options]="{customPrefix: {public: ''}}">
</amplify-s3-image>
```

The mainImage-Object was uploaded via amplify graphql and looks like this:

```
"mainImage": {
    "bucket": "bucketname",
    "region": "eu-central-1",
    "key": "public/b369e63d-1a40-4793-ae49-cecde042b1b9.jpg",
    "__typename": "S3Object"
  },
```

I can't find any documentation for this, so here is the link to the [code on github](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/master/packages/aws-amplify-angular/src/components/storage/s3-image-component/s3-image.component.core.ts).